# R data.table add class column

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to build a `data.table` having a column containing class objects? When trying to set a column to store an object of class `hclust` I get errors (repeatable example below).

```
library(fastcluster)
library(data.table)
D<-dist(c(1,2,3,22,23))
C<-hclust(D, method="average")
class(C)
[1] "hclust"
dtTrials<-data.table(Idx=1L) # data.table of 1 trial
dtTrials[Idx==1, Clust:=C] # add the hclust object for trial #1
Error in `[.data.table`(dtTrials, Idx == 1, `:=`(Clust, C)) : 
  Supplied 7 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'Clust'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

What I'm looking for is a `data.table` like this:

| Idx | Clust |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (object of class hclust) |
| 2 | (another object of class hclust) |
| etc... | ... |

Comment: consider listing the objects

Comment: try `dtTrials[Idx==1, Clust:=.(C)]`

Comment: Thanks, looks like listing it will work. dtTrials[Idx==1, Clust:=.(C)]  class(dtTrials[1]$Clust[[1]])  [1] "hclust"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @ThomasIsCoding and @onyambu. The trick is to store it as a list. The original `hclust` object can then be referenced using `[[`.

```
dtTrials[Idx==1, Clust:=.(C)]
class(dtTrials[1]$Clust[[1]])
[1] "hclust"
```